# Get the options and attribute titles of an order item in a specific language programmatically

Tags: magento-1.9

I need the options and attribute titles of an order item  in a specific language programmatically.

```
$options = $sItem->setStoreId(2)->getProductOptions();
```

Is not working

Comment: I guess your product options are product attributes, isn't it?

Comment: When an order is done, the product attributes are returned in the object in the language that the buyer selected. But we need them in the language that is standard in the magento store.

Answer (score 0):

I am answering your question on the assumption of "**product options are added as attributes**". I used the sample variable `wk_year`.

```
<?php
       $wk_year = $_product->getWkYear(); 
       //This is how get the product attribute from product in product page.This is value of a product option(drop down.)
        $attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_option')
                ->getCollection()
                ->setOrder("option_id","ASC")
                ->setStoreFilter()
                    ->join('attribute','attribute.attribute_id=main_table.attribute_id', 'attribute_code')
                        ->addFieldToFilter('main_table.option_id',array('in'=>$wk_year));


        foreach ($attr as $option) {
            echo "<br/>".$option->getValue();//This is Label of a product option(drop down.)
        }
```

Comment: Is this code for a order item? The main problem is: When an order is done, the product attributes are returned in the object in the language that the buyer selected. But we need them in the language that is standard in the magento store. Basically we need to be able to change the language of the options (keys and values) when they are returned in the order (orderitem).